# POST endpoint is receiving null values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a POST request. The method parameters are `null`. I have verified the call and it seems fine to me. Any suggestions appreciated.

```js
var WebServiceURL = 'https://localhost:44341/api/controllername/ForwardInfo'
$.ajax({
  type: webServiceRequestMethod,
  url: WebServiceURL,
  data: JSON.stringify(objSendData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {}
  failure: function() {}
})
```

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Ask4Purple/FowardInfo")]
public IActionResult FowardInfo(string zipcode, int searchRadius, string ProductCodes)
//public IActionResult FowardInfo([FromBody] ListOfStores value)
{
  string Zipcode = zipcode;
  int SearchRadius = searchRadius;
  string ProductCode = ProductCodes;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the content of `objSendData`? Also note that your `Route` attribute is setting the URL to `api/Ask4Purple/FowardInfo`, not the URL you've actually used in the JS

Comment: Yes its the problem with Routing and some other old code i didn't comment. Thanks for your points

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `POST` method receive a viewModel which contains all those properties:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public int searchRadius { get; set; }
    public string ProductCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Besides, maybe you have a typo in your OP that your use `FowardInfo` on route attribute while js url uses `ForwardInfo`.

Below is a working demo:

1.Ajax

```
var WebServiceURL = 'https://localhost:44341/api/Ask4Purple/ForwardInfo';
var objSendData = {
    zipcode: "123",
    searchRadius: 5,
    ProductCodes: "001"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: WebServiceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(objSendData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { }

})
```

2. Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Ask4PurpleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("ForwardInfo")]

    public IActionResult ForwardInfo([FromBody] MyViewModel value)
    {
        string Zipcode = value.zipcode;
        int SearchRadius = value.searchRadius;
        string ProductCode = value.ProductCodes;
        // ...
        return new JsonResult(value);
    }
}
```

3.Result:

[image]